# TableSorter jQuery Plugin - Enable Select Element in Disabled Header Column

Tags: tablesorter

I am using the TableSorter jQuery plugin. I'm trying to place a select element as one of my column headers. I've disabled that particular column for sorting by doing this:

```
 $('#rankings').tablesorter(headers: {5: {sorter:false}});
```

But when I click on the select element in the column header the options don't populate. It's as if there is something "blocking" me from clicking on it.

Is there something in the TableSorter code that will disable clicking on the element if it is disabled?

I was even experimenting on their example [page](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html), and you can't even seem to highlight the text in the column headers for those column headers that are disabled.

Is there any way to place a select in a disabled column header using TableSorter? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an undocumented option `cancelSelection` which can be set to `false` ([missing docs post](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html)), then you'll need to use the `onRenderHeader` to disable selection on the other headers (if you want) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/473/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    // make header text selectable
    cancelSelection: false,
    headers: {
        0: {
            sorter: false
        }
    },    
    // prevent text selections (optional)
    onRenderHeader: function (index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            $(this)
                .addClass('no-select')
                .attr('unselectable', 'on')
                .bind('selectstart', false);
        }
    }
});
```